# fastest way to pass large objects

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, optimization, reference

Take the following function as a example

```
string print()
{
   return (some string that has been formed);
};
```

and now lets say that this print function will form a ridiculously large string, that needs to get back to the function that called it from another class.

Now say this print function may be called thousands of times. Is there a correct and faster way to do this?

In Visual Studio you can do this

```
void print(string& lines)
{
   lines = (some string that has been formed);
};
```

however g++ will not compile this, nor should it be done this way as this could be a temporary object that could disappear at any second. So from what I understand is I could do this

```
void print(const string& lines)
{
};
```

if all I wanted was to retrieve something in this string w/o modifying it and do it very quickly. But I do want to modify it. So this I can not do.

Which leads me to the question is declaring a new pointer to a object going to be the fastest way to do this? or is it slower? or is it just not worth it. i.e. (not sure if this would even work?)

```
void print(string* lines)
{
   string formedString; // the string that has been formed
   lines = formedString&;
};
```

And finally, if I am loading object up at runtime, and adding them to a tree via:

```
void add(const ItemType& item)
{
   someNode->item = item;
};
```

The `item` was originally a temporarily stored object in the scope of the function calling this `add()`, so would assigning it to the node cause the stack of the calling function to stay around longer then wanted? Or would this be OK? Also would I later be able to edit `item`, or is it now stuck as a const?

Just questions of a learning mind :)

Comment: Return the large string you form by value.

Comment: You could allocate the string on heap and return the pointer to the string. OR the caller to the method could be responsible for passing the method a point to where the string can be stored. Either of those is pretty fast. By the way, don't worry about performance if your code is not slow.

Comment: **Pre-optimization is the root of all evil** is something a learning mind should heed.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/08/28/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil.aspx

it is evil to a point :) 

"well-known optimizations applied early are not premature"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just return the string and be done with it.

The compiler will use return value optimization (or named return value optimization) to eliminate extra copies of the string as you return it. A really new compiler will also have a move constructor and move assignment operator for `std::string`, which will give even greater assurance of accomplishing the same thing.

Edit (sorry, I originally missed the last question): assigning a value will *not* preserve anything local to a function after that function returns. When a function returns, all its local variables *will* be destroyed. If you assign a *value* from that function to something that lasts after it returns, that's no problem -- it'll be copied (or maybe moved) to the destination. If you retain a pointer or reference to that local, it'll be dangling after the function returns, so trying to use the reference or dereference the pointer will lead to UB.

Depending on the situation, the latter *may* be a case where you want to use a `shared_ptr`, so both the function and the outside code will share access to the data, and the data will be destroyed only when *both* references to it are destroyed.

Comment: what about my final question where you have a generic type, and will later store it longer then the scope of the function that declared it may last? pass that by value or by const reference? (I know reference is the value of the address)

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, or a compiler with basic C++11 features, the answer is:

Want speed?  Pass by value, with objects that support move semantics.

And your `string` type (be it a `std::string` or what have you) should support fast move semantics.

If you return a local variable from a function, under C++11 it will be implicitly moved into the return value.  If your function's body is visible from the callers site, and you have one variable that is a return value from your function, then NRVO can occur resulting in no copy or move ever occurring (but rather the object being actually constructed where it ends up in the calling site).

Whenever you want to eventually make a copy of the passed in argument, similarly use pass-by-value in the parameter.  This can allow the caller to do a pass-by-move in a few contexts, and the caller can explicitly `std::move` in the non-automatic contexts, to give pretty darn good performance.

If you aren't making a copy, pass by `const string&`, which can bind to a temporary.

If you are modifying data, either pass by `string&` *or* pass by `string`, then return the new string as part of the return value.  With fast move construction, the second is nearly as fast as the first in the worst case, and in some cases can be faster (multiple chaining of NRVO is in theory possible with that second case!)

Comment: so with my `item` , you are saying I should pass it by value rather than a `const ItemType&` reference, for the reason that I will want to store/copy/modify it later? So if I did pass `item` by const reference would that be bad in the case that I will later store it longer then the scope of the function that declared it may last?

Comment: If you are going to store something, and it has a fast `move` constructor, your function should take it by value -- having fast move rocks.  And yes, keeping untracked references to things is dangerous and a maintenance headache: in some situations still done, but it requires care.